# Can I block users from my chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I currently do not have a chat room, but I was wondering, could I block annoying users from my chat room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what gandalf3 said, no you can not just block a user from your chat room.

Chat room are set up to be public, and in normal rooms there is no mechanism to banish a user from just that room.

The "*kick-mute*" feature will last (depending on how frequently the user has been kicked) 1, 5, or 30 minutes. So it is not permanent.

---

Now you can create a restricted room where only people that you let in can talk. That type of room is called a "*gallery*," only the people you have on the room's access list (and mods) will be able to talk; however anyone can view it.

Those are the only two ways a room owner can control who talks in their room. But there is no way to just block a user from talking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a room owner you'll have the ability to kick/mute users from your room.

For a full list of chat-related abilities and privileges, refer to [this answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87773/238438).